# Reduce logs in Spark with Log4j2 running on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, log4j2

I have multiple spark jobs running on Kubernetes through Google Cloud Storage. They are scheduled to run daily via Airflow.

My goal is to reduce the logging level from INFO to WARN.

So far, I have tried multiple log4j2.properties configurations, put them in the **conf directory** at `$SPARK_HOME/conf`.

In the spark job's code, I also tried the following :

```
// from org.apache.logging.log4j
LogManager.getRootLogger.atLevel(org.apache.logging.log4j.Level.WARN)

// logger used in the application : 
val log: Logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
log.setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

Changing the rootLogger is an issue because Airflow still needs a minimum of logs to be able to tell when the spark application finishes.

I still receive logs from `KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend`, `BasicExecutorFeatureStep`, `BlockManagerMaster` etc ...

```
...
23/10/05 13:15:35 INFO ExecutorPodsAllocator: Found 0 reusable PVCs from 0 PVCs
23/10/05 13:15:35 INFO BasicExecutorFeatureStep: Decommissioning not enabled, skipping shutdown script
23/10/05 13:15:38 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: No executor found for SOME.IP.ADDRESS:SOME_PORT
...
```

I'm using Spark 3.4.0 and log4j 2.15.0